# How to redirect a user to the current page?

Tags: 8, redirection, breadcrumbs

How can I redirect user to the current page using Drupal\Core\Link?

I am creating a breadcrumb where I want to redirect user to the current page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
   use Drupal\Core\Link;
   use Drupal\Core\Url;
   $redirect_to_same_page = Link::fromTextAndUrl('Same page', Url::fromUri('base:' .\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath())); 
   $breadcrumb->addLink($redirect_to_same_page);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this you get the actual path:

```
\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()
```

and then you just use it as:

```
$current_page_link = new Drupal\Core\Link('So here you are', Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('base:' . Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()));
```

Comment: Alternatively the URL can be built with `Url::fromRoute(\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName())`

Answer (score 0):

Using Route.
Drupal get the current route name

```
$route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
// or
// $current_route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
$this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Page redirected'));
return $this->redirect($route_name);
```

Reference: https://www.codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/get-route-name-current-page-drupal-8